# Partial-Content с кодом 200. Как это возможно?

Tags: flash, nginx

С некоторого реально существующего ресурса получаю, при смене позиции видео во flash-проигрывателе запрос `filename.flv?start=31379682`.

Запрос такой:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:ShockwaveFlash/17.0.0.169
```

Ответ:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:448245079
Content-Type:video/x-flv
Date:Wed, 13 May 2015 06:51:36 GMT
ETag:"543b98b0-1ab7ad57"
Last-Modified:Mon, 13 Oct 2014 09:17:36 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.2
```

Однако:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Вопрос: Каким образом файл отдаётся частями с 200 кодом?
P.S. Заметил, что при смене позиции меняется и значение Content-Length на меньшее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, то выходит так: начальная позиция передается в GET-переменной start. Вычисляем длину получившегося куска файла, как filesize-start. Потом выдаем получившееся значение в Content-Length, делаем в файле fseek на позицию start - и с этой позиции выдаем уже поток данных с кодом 200.

Comment: То есть filesize-start = (Content-Length) - start, верно?

Comment: Если start=0, тогда Content-Length = filesize. А если start будет больше ноля, то при выдаче нужно Content-Length уменьшить, сделать равным filesize-start. Значение filesize - это размер файла filename.flv на диске.

Comment: Понял. Тогда ещё небольшой дополнительный вопрос. Зачем так делают? Какой мотив такого решения? Разве эти небольшие ухищрения не делают большую нагрузку на сервер? Почему не разрешают Partial Content (Range) почти нигде?

Comment: Тут сложно сказать, надо интересоваться у владельцев ресурса. Вполне может быть, что такой подход быстрее и экономичнее с точки зрения ресурсов сервера, чем добавлять полную поддержку Partial Content.

Answer (score 0):

Это целый видеофайл, начинающийся с конкретного момента, а не часть другого файла, вырезанная, начиная с какого-то байта. В случае наличия у формата префикса (а у flv он вроде есть), это вообще не эквивалентно.